# Data from a list php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would you to know how to get data from a list in php.

```
<h1>Liste livres</h1>
<ul>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <?php
            $liste = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM livres");
            while($l = $liste->fetch()){
        ?>
        <li><input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="<?php echo $l['livre_isbn']; ?>"/>\<?= $l['livre_titre'] ?>\<?= $l['livre_auteur'] ?>\<?= $l['livre_genre'] ?>\<?= $l['dispo'] ?></li>
        <button name="empr" type="submit">Emprunter</button>
        <?php } ?>
    </form>
</ul>
```

Every time I click on "Emprunter" for any element displayed, he only take the last element of the list in the procedure. How can I make sure it takes the right element?
For information, the element in the list used is `$['livre_isbn']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `<form>` tag in your `while` loop :-)

Comment: (So you can accept the answer, other people would want to find the anwser easily :) )

Comment: Man you guys really get on your knees for just 1 hit of accept.